# Rails can't find a temporary directory when run inside Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I have Dockerized a very simple Rails 5 app (*and its PostgreSQL database*) with Docker compose. When I run it natively, it works fine, but if I run it inside the Docker container, and go to the homepage, I receive the following error:

```
web_1  | ActionView::Template::Error (could not find a temporary directory):
web_1  |      9:     <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
web_1  |     10:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
web_1  |     11: 
web_1  |     12:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
web_1  |     13:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
web_1  |     14:     <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
web_1  |     15:   </head>
web_1  |   
web_1  | app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1331678602890151203_70235895526140'
web_1  |   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
web_1  |   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
web_1  |   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (6.5ms)
web_1  |   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
web_1  |   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.6ms)
web_1  |   Rendering /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
web_1  |   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.1ms)
web_1  |   Rendered /usr/local/bundle/gems/actionpack-5.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (35.4ms)
```

I've read in other posts that it may depend on the permissions of the `/tmp` directory inside the container, so I gave it full permissions, and I've also tried to specify the `TMPDIR` directory for the container, but it didn't worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same issue I supposed that your docker root is not '/var/lib/docker' but located somewhere else in your file system tree.

In my case the docker root was located on an external SSD formatted with NTFS. However, this filesystem did not support the required permissions for the temporary directory which is under '/tmp/'. So I resized the disk, created an additional EXT4 partition and configured docker to store its data on that partition. This solved the issue.

If this does not work try the following command:
    chmod +t /tmp
for example:
    chmod +t /var/lib/docker/tmp